# Access the facebook login button programmatically

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have shared preference activity, and I save my username and password in my shared preference. Now, I need to just get that particular string, to the take it as a username and password. And I need to log in using that particular facebook account.

I'm using this Facebook sdk: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/

I'm new to android. Kindly guide me to access facebook login button.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook provides a pretty good Tutorial on how to use their SDK:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

Comment: thank you for your reply.actually my need is user given the log in details in my preference edit text.after that i need to take that details into the Facebook login browser tape and click the login button.is there any api for click the login button without user interaction.